# equality check between CharSequence and String objects with possible null values in java

Tags: java

I have a `CharSequence` object and a `String` object. I want to compare both for equality check(case insensitivity) with possible `null` values. I used nested `if` statements which is not so clean and optimised. Problem is I cannot call `toString()` on a `null` CharSequence object. How can I achieve equality check ?

Comment: What if both are null? Should they be considered as equal?

Comment: Yes @DanielePantaleone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, it is this:
You have two objects, and you want to see if they're equal.

What we'd WANT to do is to use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-). It's literally precisely what you want.
If the CharSequence object is not null, it's pretty easy, because [`CharSequence.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString--) returns a string with the exact same characters in the exact same order.

```
charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(otherString);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. If the charsequence is null, then this throws a NullPointerException. So we need to see if the charsequence is null, and proceed from there.

```
public boolean compareCSAndString(CharSequence cs, String string) {
  if(cs == null) {
    // If both are null, then they're equal
    return string == null; 
  }
  else {
    return cs.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string);
  }
}
```

This ticks all the boxes:

- It's case insensitive
- It handles null values
- It is clean and easy to read *(no nested ifs)*

Comment: You could simplify as   `public boolean compareCSAndString(CharSequence cs, String string) {
       return cs != null ? cs.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string) :   false;
     }`

Comment: Is that simpler though? I get that it's shorter, but simpler to read wins every single time for me. I guess it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no much complicated code and no nested `if`'s. Below should do.

```
if(Objects.equals(charSeq,str) || (charSeq !=null && str !=null && charSeq.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str))) {
   // todo
}
```

Comment: what if charSeq is null and str is not null ?

Comment: This doesn't cover the OP request: "case insensitive check" ;)

Comment: @XoXo Then they are not equal and you get control to else statement.

Comment: Great, but use *equalsIgnoreCase* to make your answer more correct.

Comment: So, I did an hour research and found out that `equalsIgnoreCase` method solve the problem. ;)

Comment: I tried your code. But when both objects are null. Its going to `else` part

Comment: @XoXo If both are null, you treat them they are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Using directly `equals()` will not work as `equals()` of `CharSequence` subclasses  are  not interoperable between. 
You could use the `toString()` method as a bridge between the `CharSequence` subclasses as it is interoperable in some cases (`String` and `StringBuilder` for example) but it is not in all cases.

For example invoking `toString()` on a `CharBuffer` object may give a specific result  as `CharBuffer.toString()` relies on the buffer current position .

To have consistent results, I think that you have not other choice that first checking the type of the object passed and then perform the comparison consequently : using `toString()` as bridge for `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` and handle differently other types.

For the bridge comparison, supposing that you expect only `StringBuilder` or `String` as subclasses:

```
public boolean compareContent(CharSequence charSequence, String string) {
  if (!(charSequence instanceof StringBuilder || charSequence instanceof String){
      // Exception, logging, more customized comparison or return false
  }
  return charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (charSeq == str ||  (charSeq != null && str != null && charSeq.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str))) {
   // todo
}
```

`charSeq == str` handle the case when both are null (only this case since they belong to different classes and cannot then identify the same object reference